# MongoDB: How to speed up my data reorganisation query/operation?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to analyse some data and I thought my queries would be faster ultimately by storing a relationship between my collections instead. So I wrote something to do the data normalisation, which is as follows:

```
var count = 0;
db.Interest.find({'PersonID':{$exists: false}, 'Data.DateOfBirth': {$ne: null}})
.toArray()
    .forEach(function (x) {
    if (null != x.Data.DateOfBirth) {
        var peep = { 'Name': x.Data.Name, 'BirthMonth' :x.Data.DateOfBirth.Month, 'BirthYear' :x.Data.DateOfBirth.Year};
        var person = db.People.findOne(peep);
        if (null == person) {
            peep._id = db.People.insertOne(peep).insertedId;
            //print(peep._id);
        }

        db.Interest.updateOne({ '_id': x._id }, {$set: { 'PersonID':peep._id }})

        ++count;
        if ((count % 1000) == 0) {
            print(count + ' updated');
        }
    }
})
```

This script is just passed to mongo.exe.

Basically, I attempt to find an existing person, if they don't exist create them. In either case, link the originating record with the individual person.

However this is very slow! There's about 10 million documents and at the current rate it will take about 5 days to complete.

Can I speed this up simply? I know I can multithread it to cut it down, but have I missed something?

Comment: Processing result one-by-one (with `forEach()`) and running `findOne`, `updateOne`, `updateOne` inside is the worst you can do. Actually, I would have no idea how to run it even slower!

Comment: Condition `'Data.DateOfBirth': {$ne: null}` and `if (null != x.Data.DateOfBirth)` is redundant. Can you provide some sample input data and desired result? I think it can be done with simple aggregation pipeline and you don't even need [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That makes sense, but can you suggest a better way?

Comment: As written, please provide some sample data, then I can have a look.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes that condition is redundant, sorry. I added the latter before the former.

Comment: Please edit your question and put additional information there instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert new persons into `People` collection, use this one:

```
db.Interest.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         Name: "$Data.Name",
         BirthMonth: "$Data.DateOfBirth.Month",
         BirthYear: "$Data.DateOfBirth.Year",
         _id: 0
      }
   },
   {
      $merge: {
         into: "People",
         // requires an unique index on {Name: 1, BirthMonth: 1, BirthYear: 1}
         on: ["Name", "BirthMonth", "BirthYear"] 
      }
   }
])
```

For updating `PersonID` in `Interest` collection use this pipeline:

```
db.Interest.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "People",
         let: {
            name: "$Data.Name",
            month: "$Data.DateOfBirth.Month",
            year: "$Data.DateOfBirth.Year"
         },
         pipeline: [
            {
               $match: {
                  $expr: {
                     $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$Name", "$$name"] },
                        { $eq: ["$BirthMonth", "$$month"] },
                        { $eq: ["$BirthYear", "$$year"] }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 1 } }
         ],
         as: "interests"
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         PersonID: { $first: "$interests._id" },
         interests: "$$REMOVE"
      }
   },
   { $merge: { into: "Interest" } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OwRYh2omZhP)